# Change RDS gateway target RDP port

Tags: rds

I am using server 2008r2 RDS gateway in my environment.
All the sessions hosts on my RDS farm listen for RDP on port 4000 instead of 3389.

Is there any way to change the target port of the RDS Gateway?

I have been looking in the registry and the RPC virtual directory in RDweb put I can't find the original port 3389 specified anywhere.

Please advise.

Comment: Normally you would specify this on the client as part of the destination address.

Answer (score -1):

This can be set in the "remoteapp" console.